# Integral Representation of Symmetric Polynomial Sums

Tags: combinatorics, symmetric-polynomials

How can we reduce the summation
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{N} \dfrac{\binom{2N}{2k}}{\binom{N}{k}} \lambda^k\, \Pi_{k}(x_1, \ldots, x_N),
\end{equation}
where ($\Pi_{k}(x_1, \ldots, x_N)$ is the $k$th elementary symmetric polynomial in $N$ variables)
to a single expression? (Possibly even to a single integral in the real or complex plane?)

As a check, for $x_i = x_0$ for all $i$, we should find
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{N} \binom{2N}{2k}(\lambda x_0)^k = \frac{1}{2}\Big[ \left(1 + \sqrt{\lambda x_0}\right)^{2N} + \left(1 - \sqrt{\lambda x_0}\right)^{2N}\Big].
\end{equation}

**Background**

The elementary symmetry polynomials $\Pi_k(x_1, \ldots, x_N)$ can be indirectly defined via
$$
\prod_{\ell=1}^{N}(1+ \lambda x_{\ell}) = \sum_{k = 0}^{N} \lambda^k \, \Pi_{k}(x_1, \ldots, x_N). 
$$

Comment: What does $\Pi_k$ mean?

Comment: It stands for the $k$th elementary symmetric polynomial. I have made a correction to the problem description to reflect this.